# Cuda same kernel, but different results with __constant__

Tags: cuda, gpu

How can cudaMemcpyToSymbol just make this ??

```c
// head.h
#include <stdio.h>
__constant__ float const_mem[1];

__global__ void k0();   //I will declare it in main.cu
__global__ void k1();   //I will declare it in separate.cu
```

```
//separate.cu
#include "head.h"

__global__ void k0() {
     printf("%f\n", const_mem[0]);
}
```

```
//main.cu
#include "head.h"

__global__ void k1() {
     printf("%f\n", const_mem[0]);
}

int main() {
     float arr[] = {5};
     cudaMemcpyToSymbol(const_mem, arr, sizeof(float));
     k0<<<1,1>>>();
     k1<<<1,1>>>();
}
```

Compilation : `nvcc main.cu separate.cu`

output of `sudo nvprof ./a.out`  (`./a.out` gives litteraly nothing)

```
0.000000
5.000000
```

That mean that kernel writed in an other transition unit is not accessing const_memory ... but how is it possible ??

Comment: the reason `./a.out` gives literally nothing is that you should have a `cudaDeviceSynchronize()` after your kernel calls.

Comment: ok thanks, but why programme do not wait until kernel end ?

Comment: because kernel launches are asynchronous, and you don't have any code in your program that tells it to wait until kernel end.